# What are the main differences between pranotthana and kundalini?

Tags: yoga, shakti, kundalini

I have basic understanding of what the Kundalini Shakti is but there is another energy that starts from mooladhara and ascends the spinal cord via pingala nadi, it is known as **pranotthana**.

My question:

1. What is the main purpose of this energy?
2. What are the basic differences between these two energies?

References from authentic resources would be useful.

Comment: Btw "prAnotthAna" simply means "the ascent of prAna" (upward movement of prAna). Do you hv any references which show Kundalini and the other as comparable/similar entities?

Comment: @Rickross I read about pranotthana in kundalini tantra but nothing much is written about it in the book.

Comment: its same, Kundalini is Prana and its uprising is called Prana+Uttana(uprising). It is mentioned in Upanishads as Prana of Purusha(supersoul/self Brahman)

Comment: I dont think there are different for ascent via ida or pingala..

Comment: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_1/Raja-Yoga/The_Psychic_Prana

Comment: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_1/Raja-Yoga/The_Psychic_Prana